# The filter "number_format_decimal" does not exist in SonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:edit.html.twig at line 54

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

SonataMediaBundle used to work correctly. Since I installed and configured SonataPageBundle it doesn't work anymore .. At first, I had a `500 Internal Server Error` as a response (I created the default site, the default pages and the default snapshots) and the rest of the pages worked fine ! then I installed and configured SonataFormatterBundle and then I don't know why when I try to upload a file or a youtube link I got this error :

```
The filter "number_format_decimal" does not exist in SonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:edit.html.twig at line 54
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Syntax
```

I also have `SonataIntlBundle` activated in my `AppKernel.php`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add this line to your `composer.json`

```
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "2.2.x-dev",
```

then update composer by this command

```
    composer update "sonata-project/intl-bundle"
```

after that add this line to `AppKernel.php`

```
    new Sonata\IntlBundle\SonataIntlBundle(),
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: It is `AppKernel.php` I guess.